# Overwriting the >> operator for derived classes

Tags: c++

I have a program I am working on that requires us to overload the >> for the Employee class so that when it's used it reads in the right type of employee so I have something like this in my main program:

```
 Employee *emp;
 empIn >> emp;
```

I figured the base class is where I would want to do it, because it is the only one that applies to all of the derived classes.  The type is determined by an integer at the start of the line so I figured that something like this might work (as I don't know the type until I read it):

```
istream &operator >> (istream &stream, Employee &emp)
{
   int type;
   stream >> type;
   switch(type){
      case 1:
         *emp = new Hourly;
         break;
           ...
   }
   return stream;
}
```

But, it doesn't work.  I'm I going about this the right way?  And if not, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't?"

Comment: That should be `Employee*& emp`

Comment: It doesn't work, it won't compile

Comment: @K-ballo, thanks you're a life saver.  I could not figure out the missing * for the life of me.  Place it in an answer and I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to your istream function should be `Employee* &emp` if you want to be able to assign to the pointer as in your example usage.  The type would then be a reference to a pointer, which lets you assign it as you want to do instead the method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, it seems, is that you mix references and pointer. In the `operator>>` function, you receive `emp` as a reference, but access it as a pointer, which is wrong.

For the whole thing to work, the `emp` object needs to be allocated *before* you try to input to it. You can not allocate it inside the function.

```
Employe emp;
empIn >> emp;
```

Or

```
Employe *emp = new Employe;
empIn >> *emp;
```

And of course, don't use `new` inside the function.

The compiler should have given you quite a lot of errors for this, you should check out what they say first.

Comment: I did check the error and all it said was that '=' no operator matches these operands.  The reason I didn't do Employee *emp = new Employee is because the .h file we were given by our professor has a pure virtual function preventing that.  So, it has to be overloaded so that it can create an instance of one of the derived classes.